# Transparency over multiple pictureBoxes

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I have an array of picture boxes that are arranged in a square. I want to put a larger, mostly transparent picture box over the top. But when I do it covers the other picture boxes and just draws the background of the form. 
Is there a way to get it to have all the other picture boxes show where it is transparent?

Answer (score 3):

Transparency in WinForms isn't great. Some controls have transparency support, others don't. Some controls can be subclassed to enable this (by calling `Control.SetStyle()` with the `SupportsTransparency` flag). I believe this can be done with `PictureBox`.

However, transparency in all WinForms controls works by having the transparent control call its parent control to draw the background before the child control draws. This means that you cannot have two sibling controls and expect transparency on one to show through to the other. Sorry!

All that said, it would be possible to code your own workaround to support this. It would involve subclassing `PictureBox` and clever coding in the `OnPaint` override to locate sibling controls and manually trigger painting of them into in-memory bitmaps. Lots of gotchas with this approach.

Try WPF!

Comment: Regarding the gotchas while subclassing `PictureBox`, is that inherently a gotcha-heavy experience?  Or is the asker's sibling form requirement the complex part?

Comment: I did something similar years ago, but I don't remember all the details. I remember having to be aware of the transformations and scaling and relative positions of all the controls so as to clip the output correctly. It's definitely doable, and an interesting challenge!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tip to get the desired result:

1. Create multiple copies of your top image.
2. Add each copy to the Controls of each picture box it should cover.
3. Adjust location of each copy according to the offset of each picture box to be covered.

So you will see every copy of your big image covering each picture box as if they were a single image.